# Leaflet marker - how to write inside the icon of the marker

Tags: leaflet, title, marker

I'm new with leaflet and i would to determine if it could be an alternative to google maps api.

Most of the things seem to be positive but i would like to know how to write inside the icon of a marker in a simple way. Currently i am just able to write in the attached popup.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
L.marker(e.latlng).bindPopup("Latitude :" + e.latlng.lat + "<br/> Longtitude :" + e.latlng.lng).addTo(this);
```

Check the reference on the website:

> Represents an icon to provide when creating a marker.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon

or

> Represents a lightweight icon for markers that uses a simple div
>   element instead of an image.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon

Answer (score 0):

Look into [`L.DivIcon`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#divicon), which allows you to replace marker image with custom HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The Leaflet icon has [L.DivIcon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#divicon) method which allows you to use a simple `<div>` element instead of an image. You can set your image in the `<div>` using HTML `<img>` tag, and include your text using `<span>` or any other HTML tag.

```
const icon = new L.DivIcon({
  className: 'icon-div',
  html: `<img src='./assets/images/icons/icon.png'/>
    <span>ABC</span>`,
});
```

And then set your icon:

```
const marker = L.marker([field.Latitude, field.Longitude])
  .setIcon(icon)
  .addTo(this.markerGroup);
```

And your markerGroup goes to layers:

```
this.layers.push(this.markerGroup);
```

And then set your layers to the map.

You might need to set styles to align the text on the image properly. The following CSS contains the selectors you need.

```
.leaflet-popup-content {
  width: 300px;
}
.leaflet-popup-content img {
  width: 80px;
}
.leaflet-marker-icon img {
  width: 60px;
}
.leaflet-marker-icon span {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  top: 25px;
  left: 5px;
}
```